# Change this table structure formarket basket analysis

Tags: python, market-basket-analysis

my code:

```
basket = response.groupby('user_id')[['call', 'signal','others']].apply(list) 
basket
```

what I get:

user_id

```
1        [call, signal,others]
2        [call, signal,others]
3        [call, signal,others]
4        [call, signal,others]
```

but I want to create a column with name `'final'` and all values in the `call, signal,others` will look like a list.

see what I want

```
user_id  final
1        [A, B,C]
2        [A, B]
3        [B]
4        [B]
```

NO DUPLICATE ON EACH USER ROW i.e [A,A,B,B, C]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't provide the input data, it was hard to resolve the output. Some how I manage to come up with the solution

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'user_id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'call': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    'signal': ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'others': ['C', 'A', 'B', 'B']
}
response = pd.DataFrame(data)
basket = response.groupby('user_id')[['call', 'signal', 'others']].apply(lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys(x.values.ravel())))
basket = basket.reset_index(name='final')
print(basket)
```

[image: My Output]

Comment: I'm sorry for additional  question here, is it possible to use apriori algorithm to get frequent data from the final column because I removed only user_id  so I'm going with `final` column like:  `r_list = basket["final"].tolist()` then   `frq_data = apriori(r_list, min_support=0.003, use_colnames=True)` but I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size'` any suggestion please

Comment: import pandas as pd
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules

basket = basket.set_index('user_id')['final'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies()
frequent_itemsets = apriori(basket, min_support=0.003, use_colnames=True)
rules = association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="lift", min_threshold=1)
print(frequent_itemsets)
print(rules)